# Er findet es interessant, fremde Länder kennenzulernen

Tags: sentence-structure

Can I use both forms to inquire about this statement, I mean are both forms correct?

> Womit findet er interessant?
>
> Was findet er interessant?

Background to the question: I thought that "zu + infinitive construction" can be inquired on by "womit", as in *Womit fängt Marissa bald an?* - *Sie fängt bald an, mehr Sport zu machen.*

Comment: Why do you think *Womit findet er interessant?* is a valid question? It asks about a tool used but *interessant finden* does not need nor allow a tool.

Comment: Sehr weit hergeholte Ausnahme: "Nur mit dem Herzen sieht man gut."/ "Ich seh mit den Augen gut."/"Und womit findet er interessant?"/"Mit dem Hirn, wenn er eins hat.".

Comment: I thought that "zu + infinitive construction" can be inquired on by "Womit" !
- Womit fängt Marissa bald an?  
- Sie fängt bald an, mehr Sport zu machen.

Comment: @userunknown I admire your ingenuity. Finding a use-case for that sentence was really a hard nut!

Comment: @Millen, I used your additional info given in your comment to make clear what is the actual question and to explain why you believe "Womit findet er interessant" would be a well-formed sentence (which it is not).

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann very good reform; thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die Auswahl des Frageworts hängt davon ab, welche Kasusbegleiter ein konkretes Verb hat und welche Präpositionen damit einhergehen.

> anfangen **mit** etwas (Dat.) --> **womit** anfangen?
>
> etwas interessant finden (Akk.) --> was interessant finden?
>
> jemanden der Ruhe berauben (Gen.) --> jemanden wessen berauben?
>
> viel Geld kosten (Akk.) --> was kosten?
>
> jemandem übel mitspielen (Dat.) --> wem übel mitspielen?
>
> jemandem **mit** etwas (zweimal Dat.!) übel mitspielen --> jemandem (wem?) **womit** (mit wem oder was) übel mitspielen
>
> dem Rauchen entsagen (Dat.) -> wem entsagen? (Nicht etwa: womit)
>
> **mit** dem Rauchen aufhören (Dat.) --> **womit** aufhören?
>
> dem Freund eine Wohnung finden (Dat., Akk.) --> wem was finden?

Am letzten Beispiel sieht man, dass "finden" in bestimmten Fällen auch ein Dativobjekt haben kann (wem? dem Freund). Jedoch ist das ein anderes *finden* als in *etwas interessant finden*. *Interessant finden* kann kein Dativobjekt haben, und daher kann man auch nicht *womit* fragen. Oder man muss sich dazu enorm verdrehen, wie es UserUnknown in seinem Kommentar spaßeshalber gemacht hat.

Und schließlich, aber wesentlich:

> anfangen **mit** etwas --> **womit** anfangen?

und darum entsprechend:

> anfangen, Sport zu machen --> **womit** anfangen? Oder auch: anfangen, was zu machen?

Comment: "Er fing an, es interessant zu finden, fremde Länder kennenzulernen." <g>